# How to get email open notification in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

In my rails application i am using action mailer to send mails to users. I want to give some bonus points to user if he opens the mail. For that i want to get notification when the email got opened in user end. Is there any idea to achieve this?

I tried as below.

I added one image tag in the mail template like below:

```
 <%= image_tag tracking_image_url(1)%>
```

And in controller

```
def image
  file_path=File.dirname(::Rails.root.join('public','assets','customer_ads','2','medium','medium')) + "/Huawei.jpg"
  send_file file_path, :type => 'image/jpeg'
end
```

I am not getting any notification from this. It's just downloading the image.

Comment: Is can be achieved by embedding an image with an unique URL, called *web beacon* or [web bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug).

Comment: Could u explain in detail as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I can't write a full tutorial. Do you have any specific problems implementing this?

Comment: yes. I will update my question with my code.

Comment: You should embed client_id in that url. Then later, when tracking image is requested, you'll know what client requested it.

Comment: Well, the code you wrote in your action would certainly download the file but thats not your intention. For the purpose of just getting a notification, you have to append a unique hash to the url which can identify the user that the email was sent to and you can have that saved in your db as notification. You could as well append client_id but thats not something I would do.

Comment: @PamioSolanky please explain in detail with code samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved through [ahoy email](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy_email) gem.

Comment: can you say me how did you achieved through ahoy email gem, I tried but, when I read my mail from gmail/yahoo ahoy_messages table wont update.

Comment: in mailer have you given track user: @user ??

Comment: Yep I gave and I followed same steps mentioned in the github

Comment: then it should work. Could you post your mailer code?

Comment: class SubscribeUserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 track utm_campaign: "boom"
 
  default from: "info@mysitecom"

 def subscribe(user)
  track user: user
  @url  = 'http://www.mysitecom/'
  mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Subscription Notification')
 end

end

Comment: your code is looking fine.did the user receive mail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62812/discussion-between-veeru-and-pooja-agarwal).

Comment: Yes they can receive mails